# How to get/set values to input fields using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, input

I know to get/set values to input fields using jQuery like follow example.

```
//Get
var bla = $('#txt_name').val();

//Set
$('#txt_name').val(bla);
```

I want to get/set values using data attribute. For an example, if I have following input I want to set/get values using "**data-wpt-id**".

```
<input type="text" data-wpt-id="wpcf-latitude">
```

**Note : Please note that this input field doesn't have id attribute.**

Comment: Use attr https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_attr.asp

Comment: I think you need to explain better. Do you need help with writing your selector?

Comment: If you can't select the element directly then you need to retrieve it from the surrounding HTML structure, eg `$('#container .left-column.foo input').data('wpt-id')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [Attribute Selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)

```
//Get
var bla = $('input[data-wpt-id="wpcf-latitude"]').val();

//Set
$('input[data-wpt-id="wpcf-latitude"]').val(bla);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// Get 
var bla = $('input[data-wpt-id="wpcf-latitude"]').val()

// Set
$('input[data-wpt-id="wpcf-latitude"]').val(bla)
```

Comment: Can you give some explanation

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
$('input[data-wpt-id]').val(function() {
  return $(this).data("wpt-id")
});
```

**Demo**

```js
$('input[data-wpt-id]').val(function() {
  return $(this).data("wpt-id")
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" data-wpt-id="wpcf-latitude">
```

Answer (score 0):

Following the jQuery documentation for the `data` function: https://api.jquery.com/data/

Following the Vanilla documentation for the `dataset` attribute: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOrForeignElement/dataset

Example:

```
<input type="text" class="container" data-wpt-id="5">

// jQuery
const $inputElement = $('.container');

const wptId = $inputElement.data('wptId');

console.log(wptId); // 5

$inputElement.data('wptId', 10);

console.log($inputElement.data('wptId')); // 10

// Vanilla
const inputElement = document.querySelector('.container');

const wptId= inputElement.dataset.wptId|| 0;

console.log(wptId); // 5

inputElement.dataset.wptId= 10;

console.log(inputElement.dataset.wptId); // 10


// If the `<input>` element has no Id/Class, you can use following selector instead:

const $jquery = $('input[data-wpt-id]');
const vanilla = document.querySelector('input[data-wpt-id]');
```